# Software testing advice?

Tags: testing, functional-testing, automated-tests

Where i am  working we have the following issue:
 Our current  test procedure is that our business analyst test the release based on their specifications/tests. If it passes these tests it is given to the quality dept where they test the new release and the entire system to check if something else was broken.

Just to mention that we outsource our development. Unfortunately  the release given to us is rarely tested by the developers  and thats "the relationship" we have with them these last 7 years....

As a result if the  patch/release fails the tests at the functionality testing level or at  the quality level with each patch given we need to test the whole thing again not just the release.
Is there a way we can prevent this from happening?

Comment: @JoseK: In a 7 years old project? I don't think so...

Comment: @Goran: why not? the present model is not working well

Comment: @JoseK: I agree that agile is almost always better, but it does have some preconditions, i.e. the software architecture needs to be 'change friendly' from its very basis. If it isn't then agile simply doesn't work. And I doubt that writing it from scratch is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Separate the code into independent modules so that a patch/change in one module only means you have to re-test that one module. However, due to dependencies this is effective only to a very limited degree.
- Introduce automated tests so that re-testing is not as expensive. It takes some more work at fist, but will definitely pay off in your scenario. You don't *have* to do unit test or TDD - integration tests based on capture-replay tools are often easier to introduce in your scenario (established project with manual testing process).

Answer (score 1):

Implement a continuous testing framework that you and the developers can access. Someething like [CruiseControl.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/) and [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) to automate the functional tests.

Given access, they'll be able to see nightly tests on the build.  Heck, they don't even need to test it themselves, your tests will be being run every night (or regularly), and they'll know straight away what faults they've caused, or fixed, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Define a 'Quality SLA' - namely that all unit tests must pass, all new code must have a certain level of coverage, all new code must have a certain score in some static analysis checker.

Of course anything like this can be gamed, so have regular post release debriefs where you discuss areas of concern and put in place contingency to avoid it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Implement GO server with Dashboard and handle with GO Agent GUI at your end.

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/forms/form/go/download[link text](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/forms/form/go/download)